# WPF - Encapsulate custom Canvas in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, scrollviewer

I need to have a Custom Panel that acts as a Canvas but really is a ScrollViewer with a Canvas inside. The user should be able to add controls like in a canvas; I need the ScrollViewer wrapper to handle zoom and pan behaviours.

So, I started writing the control:

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class MyContainer : ScrollViewer, IAddChild
{
    private Canvas _innerCanvas;

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get { return _innerCanvas.Children; }
    }

    public MyContainer()
    {
        this._innerCanvas = new Canvas();
        this.Content = _innerCanvas;

        _innerCanvas.Height = this.ActualHeight;
        _innerCanvas.Width = this.ActualWidth;
    }

    void IAddChild.AddChild(object value)
    {
        _innerCanvas.Children.Add(value as UIElement);
    }

    void IAddChild.AddText(string text)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. If I try to use it in XAML

```
<Controls:MyContainer>
    <TextBlock Height="92" Canvas.Left="324" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock 1" Canvas.Top="267" Width="284"/>
    <TextBlock Height="92" Canvas.Left="462" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock 1" Canvas.Top="267" Width="284"/>
</Controls:MyContainer>
```

the children aren't visible.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the size of your canvas to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` at the Ctor, but they are not yet initialized at that point. `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are only meaningful when the control is presented on the screen. Try to subscribe to the Loaded event of the ScrollViewer, and change the Canvas size then:

```
public MyContainer()
{
    this._innerCanvas = new Canvas();
    this.Content = _innerCanvas;

    this.Loaded += ScrollViewer_Loaded;
}

public void ScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _innerCanvas.Height = this.ActualHeight;
    _innerCanvas.Width = this.ActualWidth;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. BUT there is another problem. The controls inside the MyContainer control are fixed. In XAML Editor I can't move them with the mouse.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. I try to avoid the designer whenever I can. Just update the values manually. It's better to write xaml like this anyway, since the designer has the tendency to add a lot of extra code that you don't need, If you must, then try to design the controls in a different canvas and than copy the code to yours.

Comment: I agree with you, but the main goal of this control is to be used via XAML graphic editor. Do you know what makes the children "moveable" in a container?

Comment: Nope. The designer is really complex, and not the most stable product. In essence it compiles and runs your code with deliberate changes (for example, it changes the click functionality, so it won't execute your method, but select the control in the designer). Try to ask a different question with the proper tags, I hope you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll mark this question as answered and try with another appropriated question.